# Angular2+ : what is the simplest way to implement a simple file upload? my code is terribly not working

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

i made a mean stack crud board and it works well. (angular2+, node.js, express, mongoDB)

after i tried to add upload function and it doesn' work.
this is error message.

```
compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'uploader' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("           <label for="file">파일</label>

          <input type="file" name="single" ng2FileSelect [ERROR ->][uploader]="uploader" >
            <button type="button" (click)="uploader.uploadAll()">
         "): ng:///BoardModule/BoardCreateComponent.html@22:57
```

I've done making upload function by jsp but it's way more complicated.

do you have any idea of making upload function?

i would like to create a post with title, author, file 3 inputs

i uploaded my code github as well.

this is full code in github.

https://github.com/9aram/code-test

board-create.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BoardService } from '../../services/board.service';
import { Board } from '../../models/Board';

import {FileUploader} from 'ng2-file-upload';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-board-create',
  templateUrl: './board-create.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class BoardCreateComponent {

  //파일 업로드 요청url
  uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({
    url:'http://localhost:3000/board-create'
  });

  fileInfo = {
    originalname:'',
    filename:''
  };

  board: any = {};

  constructor(private router: Router, private boardService: BoardService) {
    //업로드 요청 결과 받아오는 메소드
    this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item, response, status, header) =>{
      this.fileInfo=JSON.parse(response);
    };
  }


  saveBoard(boardForm) {
    boardForm.form.value.originalname= this.fileInfo.originalname;
    boardForm.for.value.filename=this.fileInfo.filename;

    this.boardService.insertBoard(this.board)
      .subscribe((res: Board) => { this.router.navigate(['/boards']); }, (err) => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

board-create.component.html

```
<form #boardForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveBoard(boardForm)">
    <div class="field">
      <div class="control">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input required name="title" id="title" [(ngModel)]="board.title" type="text" class="input">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="control">
        <label for="author">Author</label>
        <input required name="author" id="author" [(ngModel)]="board.author" type="text" class="input">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <div class="control">
        <label for="file">파일</label>

      <input type="file" name="single" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" >
        <button type="button" (click)="uploader.uploadAll()">
        <<span>uploadd..</span>
        </button>

      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="field">
      <div class="control">
        <button class="button is-warning" routerLink="/boards"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>Back</button>
        <button class="button is-link" type="submit" [disabled]="!boardForm.valid">Create</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

node > api.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Board = require('../models/Board.js');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const upload=require('../util/upload');


// API ROOT ROUTE
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ status: 200, result: 'success' });
});


router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  let newBoard = new Board({
    title : request.body.title
  }),
  newBoard.save();
  response.type("application/json");
  response.send({
    result:true
  });
});

// GET ALL BoardS
router.get('/board', (req, res, next) => {
    Board.find((err, products) => (err) ? next(err) : res.json(products));
});


// GET A Board
router.get('/board/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    Board.findById(req.params.id, (err, post) => (err) ? next(err) : res.json(post));
});

// SAVE A Board
router.post('/board', upload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
    response.type("application/json");
    response.send({result:true,
    originalname: request.file.originalname,
  filename: request.file.filename()});
    Board.create(req.body, (err, post) => (err) ? next(err) : res.json(post));
});

module.exports = router;
```

upload.js

```
const multer = require('multer');


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  description:function(request, file, cb){
    cb(null, __dirname + '/../upload');
  }
  filename: function(request, file, cb){
    let datetimestamp=Date.now();
    let originalFileName=file.originalname;

    originalFileName=originalFileName.split('.');
    let originalName=originalFileName[originalFileName.length - 1];

    cb(null, file.filename + '-' + datetimestamp+ '.'+originalName);
  }

});
//starage 객체만들어 multer의 멤버 설정
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage
})
//외부에서 upload객체 사용할 수 있또록 함
module.exports = upload;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try to implement the same by checking the below code.

```
ust call uploadFile(url, file).subscribe() to trigger an upload

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpRequest, HttpEvent} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class UploadService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // file from event.target.files[0]
  uploadFile(url: string, file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('upload', file);

    let params = new HttpParams();

    const options = {
      params: params,
      reportProgress: true,
    };

    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', url, formData, options);
    return this.http.request(req);
  }
}
```

You can get further information via below link.

https://appdividend.com/2018/05/25/angular-6-file-upload-tutorial/

Comment: that link you gave me works perfectly! thanks a lot! the thing left is I need to apply to my code and DB! can I leave my next question by comment later?